# Aws ingress controller setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have try to expose my micro-service to the internet with aws ec2. Using the deployment and service yaml file under below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: XXX
        ports:
        - name: my-app
          containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: my-app
    nodePort: 32000
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
```

And also create a ingress resource.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.myApp.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /my-app
          backend:
            serviceName: my-app
            servicePort: 80
```

The last step I open the 80 port in aws dashboard, how should I choice the ingress controller to realize my intend?

Comment: Are you using kubernetes managed service from AWS or its your own setup on AWS?

Comment: I using the kubeadm to create cluster with many aws ec2 node.

Comment: Do you have any error? With what you have issue? If you are using AWS its not better to use some EKS LB or Ingress?

Answer (score 2):

`servicePort` should be 3000, the same as `port` in your service object.

Note however that, setting up cluster with kubeadm on AWS is not the best way to go: EKS provides you optimized, well configured clusters with external load-balancers and ingress controllers.